# How elements in Vandermonde’s formula be well-defined?

Tags: combinatorics

Vandermonde’s formula:

> For any non-negative integers: $m, n, k$ $${m+n \choose k}=\sum_{j=0}^k{m \choose j}{n \choose k-j}$$

For ${x \choose y}$ to be defined, $x\geq y$. But in Vandermonde’s formula, there are possibly cases where $j=m+1>m$ or $k-j=n+1>n$. So how can ${m \choose j}={m \choose m+1}$ and ${n \choose k-j}={n \choose n+1}$ be defined?

Comment: You can see this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html). I think it should be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically speaking, $\binom mn$ is the number of ways of choosing $n$ objects out of $m$, or the number of subsets of size $n$, of a subset of size $m$. There are *no* subsets of size $n$ if $n > m$, so $\binom mn$ should be defined as $0$ in this case.

---

Furthermore, when we look at a proof of Vandermonde's identity via sets, this makes even more sense :

$\binom{m+n}k$ is the number of subsets of size $k$ of a set with size $m+n$. Let us call the big set as $A$.

Alternatively, partition $A = B \ \cup \ C$, where $|B| = m,|C| = n$ and the union is therefore disjoint.  The choice of $B$ and $C$ does not matter.

Now, for any subset $K \subset A$, $K = K \cap A  = (K \cap B) \cup (K \cap C)$, where the union is disjoint.

Therefore, any such $K$ is formed by taking a subset of $B$ and a subset of $C$ whose sum of cardinalities is $|K|$.

Consequently, the answer is given as follows : for each $j = 0 \to k$, any subset of $B$ of size $j$ can be combined with any subset of $B$ of size $k-j$, and the number of ways of doing this is $\binom mj \binom n{k-j}$(**even if $\mathbf{k -j> n}$ or $\mathbf{m > j}$**), which then gets summed  to give the answer.

Hence, the interpretation of $\binom mn = 0$ if $n > m$ works out with this logic.

Comment: Did you mean "or the number of subsets of size $n$, of a *set* of size $m$", rather than "or the number of subsets of size $n$, of a *subset* of size $m$"?

Comment: And "with any subset of $C$ of size $k−j$" rather than  "with any subset of $B$ of size $k−j$"?

Comment: Both are mistakes , and I will correct them. It is key that you understand why the binomial relation holds.